# How to copy a foreign key constrained table to another database?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to replace gibberish data on my development server (recovering it from the production server).

I first tried using SSMS's "import data" task, but encountered an error saying: "Cannot truncate a table with a foreign key constraint" therefore I resolved to do the following:

1. Create a new temp copy of the table on the development server (to avoid accessing it from the production database).
2. Write an update script.

This is my script:

```
DECLARE @IdToCopy INT;
DECLARE @cnt INT;

SET @IdToCopy = 1
WHILE @IdToCopy <= 55
BEGIN
    UPDATE DocumentTypes
    SET Name = DocumentTypesTemp.Name
    FROM DocumentTypesTemp
    WHERE DocumentTypesTemp.DocumentTypeId = @IdToCopy;

    SET @IdToCopy += 1;
END;
```

I expected it to update the table to have the same values, but the only value was that of the last row from the copying table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I expected it to update the table to have the same values, but the
>   only value was that of the last row from the copying table.

In each iteration of `while` loop, your entire `DocumentTypes` table is getting updated. This is the reason, you see only last record name appearing in the entire table, you have to join the source and destination table based on the id.

```
UPDATE dest 
SET    dest.NAME = src.NAME 
FROM   documenttypes dest 
       INNER JOIN documenttypestemp src 
               ON src.documenttypeid = dest.documenttypeid
```

Above query will update the name from destination table to source table with matching `documenttypeid` in a single query.

**Note:** You don't need a while loop to update the name from source to destination.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my script using the following:

```
DECLARE @IdToCopy INT;
DECLARE @cnt INT;
DECLARE @NameToCopy varchar(256);
SET @IdToCopy=1

SELECT @cnt=COUNT(*) FROM DocumentTypesTemp;

WHILE @IdToCopy <= @cnt
BEGIN
    SELECT @NameToCopy=Name
    FROM DocumentTypesTemp 
    WHERE DocumentTypesTemp.DocumentTypeId=@IdToCopy;

    UPDATE DocumentTypes
    SET Name=@NameToCopy
    WHERE DocumentTypes.DocumentTypeId=@IdToCopy;

    SET @IdToCopy += 1;
END;
```